# I want to export the name of multiple matlab files into a .csv

Tags: excel, matlab

I want to use a for loop to export the names of a folder of .mat files into one .csv file by row.

I am trying to use xlswrite, but don't understand how to access the filename of the .mat files.

I am working with to write them to the csv.

`xlswrite(fullfile(dest_dir,'result.csv'), FILENAME HERE, ['A' num2str(i)]);`

Comment: You want all `.mat` files in a given folder in one column ?

Comment: Just the names of the .mat files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlswrite` creates a excel workbook

With `dir` command you can get a structure whose one of field is name of file.

Using simple file IO function your requirement can be met.

I think either of this will do what you need:

```
fid=fopen('result.csv','wt');

files=dir('*.mat');
x={files(:).name};

csvFun = @(str)sprintf('%s,',str);
xchar = cellfun(csvFun, x,'UniformOutput', false);
xchar = strcat(xchar{:});
xchar = strcat(xchar(1:end-1),'\n');

fprintf(fid,xchar);

fclose(fid);
```

Or

If you just need `.mat` names in a column form:

```
fid=fopen('result.csv','wt');

files=dir('*.mat');
x={files(:).name};

[rows,cols]=size(x);

for i=1:rows
  fprintf(fid,'%s,',x{i,1:end-1});
  fprintf(fid,'%s\n',x{i,end});
end

fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your filename, load the files using `dir` command, read them individually in your for loop, and then write them to file. (I think I already posted something like this?) Here is the prototype:

```
files = dir('*.mat');               % obtain all files with .mat extenstion
fid = fopen('result.csv','a');   

for k = 1:length(data)
    filename = files(k).name;       % get the filename
    fprintf(fid, '%s,\n', filename);
end

fid = fclose(fid);
```

Unfortunately, you cannot just save the file names as strings in a cell and write it as you might a matrix using say `csvwrite`, so you can just do this.